# Variational Inference for Item Response Models Estimation

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics, sufficient-statistics

I should work on a project about Variational Inference for Item Response Models Estimation.

This is my university project but I don´t find relevant information around this topic so I would be very grateful for any book you recomend me to review theory and aplications.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So is the question more about the technique of variational inference? or previous model =s of item response estimation?
Also post your question at the forum "cross-validated" may get more responses!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭  Yeah, It's about Variational Inference techniques. I have data of a survey and l'm supposed to estimate the posterior ditribution  of the latent variable.

Comment: So do you need reference or lectures for general VI techniques in ML?

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 I need some bibliographic references. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is in no way exhaustive, but it's a way to get started. (how I taught VI to myself)

[The tutorial on VI in NIPS 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogdv_6dbvVQ)

[Their accompany review paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.00670) which is really hand holding.